# C# winforms Как передать текстовое значение в combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Как передать текстовое значение в новую форму combobox? В текстбокс могу, в комбобокс - нет

```
newForm.cbStartRange.Text = StartRange.ToString(); //так не работает
newForm.tStartRange.Text = startRange.ToString(); //так работает
```

Answer (score 0):

`newForm.cbStartRange.Items.Add(startRange.ToString())` добавляет в комбобокс.

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от стиля комбобокса. Если DropDownStyle == DropDownList, то вы можете установить текст только в одно из значений из списка. Поменяйте DropDownStyle на Simple или DropDown, тогда можно будет вводить произвольный текст.

Другой ответ добавлет текст в список комбобокса.